# Resolving System Freezing / Crashes

Tags: firefox, amd, crash, ryzen

For background, I'm new to Elementary OS, but have been using Linux (mostly Ubuntu) for over a decade as a casual user (not a power user). This is the first distro that I've installed on my desktop machine. Windows is incredibly stable on this machine, but I hate dev work in Windows.

My issue is that I have encountered much more crashing and freezing than I have with other Linux experiences in the past. This primarily occurs daily, often when using Firefox. That said, I'm not sure if I can blame FF since I'm on it 95% of the time anyway.

I don't want to abandon Firefox since I prefer how I have it customized. I'm open trying other Debian-based Distros (Mint or Ubuntu), but wonder if you can switch non-destructively since the underlying Debian kernal is the same. Although it seems unlikely that this issue is Elementary OS specific right?

Any advice on what steps I should take to diagnose or fix this?

**Hardware**
Quad-Core AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics,
8GB Ram (too low, but broke my ram2 slot and with an M1 SSD things aren't that bad)

**OS**
elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera,
Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS,
Linux 5.4.0-58-generic,
GTK 3.22.30

**Browser**
Firefox 84.0, direct install

Comment: firefox is the problem try installing a different browser and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

6 month later, I am now on Elementary 6.1 Jolnir and it still crashes with monotonous regularity. The only thing I have found that gives me some hope is to disable hardware acceleration, see:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems
I think it is worth trying. Please report if it made any difference?